# No network access between docker container A and B

Tags: docker-compose

I have started two simple docker containers using `docker-compose`. Each container can access the host machine, the host machine can access each container, but the containers cannot access each other.

They are given IP address 172.19.0.2 and 172.19.0.3 so they are on the same bridge.

`nmap` shows up the ports as `filtered`.

What is wrong in my setup?

*Edit:*

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br-48718423616d         8000.0242ee6d819b       no
br-9b06de56c2e7         8000.0242f86db034       no              veth4c40427
                                                        vethf7f18db
docker0         8000.0242a8db6939       no
$ bridge link
7: vethf7f18db@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br-9b06de56c2e7 state forwarding priority 32 cost 2
9: veth4c40427@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br-9b06de56c2e7 state forwarding priority 32 cost 2
```

Comment: "_They are given IP address 172.19.0.2 and 172.19.0.3 so they are on the same bridge._" - that's a false conclusion. They are in the same subnet but not necessarily on the same bridge. To check if they really are on the same bridge use `brctrl show` or `bridge link`

Comment: Are your containers on the same Docker network?

Answer (score 0):

The host needs to allow IP forwarding.

So try `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` on the host machine.

Comment: That’s a rather big hammer...

Comment: Yes this is mentioned here in the docker doc's https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#enable-forwarding-from-docker-containers-to-the-outside-world

Comment: @AVS yes, in the context of forwarding traffic from the containers to the outside world; but that’s not what’s requested here as I understand it.